# Server Side Rendered HTML for iPhone and Andorid App (Cordova)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, cordova, mobile, app-store

Our whole app is built using server side rendered PHP. I'd like to build our mobile app using PHP templates (server side rendering) as well.

**I know I will have to provide SOME static files, but can they essentially just WRAP the app?**

The app will LOOK like a mobile app (responsive etc) and possibly have some "app only" features to distinguish it from the "web app" (if this will help us get into the iTunes store).

I haven't seen a straight forward answer to this. Actually most places say this [isn't possible](https://www.quora.com/MySQL/Can-we-use-Cordova-with-PHP-and-MySQL) but then I've seen services like https://gonative.io/ which seem to basically do just that.

Comment: the best approach is to generate JSON/XML on the server and get it from the app using XHR (ajax) calls. You can get html instead of JSON/XML, but that will require more data transfer. Just wraping the website isn't a good idea and it will be more difficult to use plugins

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking what's best I'm asking if it's possible. And I really doubt re-writing a whole existing webapp is easier then wrapping it.

Comment: I answered that too: "Just wraping the website isn't a good idea and it will be more difficult to use plugins". It isn't a good idea because apple will probably reject the app, and google might reject it too, and users usually rate apps with one star when the "app just wraps a website". And if you plan to use plugins, it's difficult to make them work when the files are online because you'll have to find a way of loading a different cordova.js depending on the device that uses your app, and make sure your users have the latest version of the app in case you updated it with a new plugin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should do this but I wanted to post an "in progress" answer to my own question. It seems this what Basecamp does (of course!) https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3743-hybrid-sweet-spot-native-navigation-web-content

We created an app using phonegap that simply loads a webview of our app, but it's mobile optimized and generally LOOKS like an app. Phone gap registers the device for push notifications then we then send push notifications via the server.

We're about to try to get into the Android store with it. From what I've heard that won't be a problem. We might have a harder time getting into the iOS store with push notifications as our only native feature though.

Comment: Kinda going down that path now with an app, using native wrappers instead of phonegap. Were you able to get into the apple app store? Is your app still being used or actively developed? Also you mentioned notifications, how did you handle per user custom notifications?

Comment: They ended up putting a hold on the project, so I never found out. The app ended up working great though!!! And, we even had custom content that was "app only" (even though technically if you knew the url you could get to it via web)